# C# - Infinite numbers

Tags: c#, winforms, numbers, nan

I'm currently work on a certain program (in C# .NET - winforms), and among the things i came across the following problem:

I need to calculate the point (t, f(t)) given that:

f(t) = [Sin(t) / 16*Cos^4(t)]^(1/3), Such that: t: -89.995 -> 89.995. (t is **real** number).

Note: the value of t is ranges from -89.995 to 89.995.

I use the .NET functions Math.Sin(), Math.Cos(), Math.Pow() for the calculations, the converssions from radians to degrees are correct and all right.

The problem is that for every t < 0 that i put in f(t) i got NaN ( = not a number) from the above functions, and when i calculate it in a standard calculator i get standard correct values.

For examplae: t = -0.9165664, f(t) = -0.1000096, (Taht's the correct result).
but when i use the .NET functions in my program, the result i get for t = -0.9165664 is NaN (= Not a Number), why? it's not an exeption, not dividing by zero or something like that.

The code i use in the program:

```
float t = -0.9165664;
float numerator = Math.Sin(t * Math.PI / 180.0f);
float denominator = 16.0f * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(t * Math.PI / 180.0f), 4)
float ft = (float)Math.Pow(numerator / denominator, 1.0f / 3.0f));
```

Note: I can't cahnge the type of ft to double.

When i put any t > 0 in the above code it gives the correct result.

Can someone explain me what wrong or suggest a possible solution?

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: What values do the numerator and denominator get in this case?

Comment: `numerator / denominator` in your example gives **-0.00100028806**. `var ft = Math.Pow(-0.00100028806f, 1.0f / 3.0f);` results in **NaN**.

Comment: It is a limitation of `Math.Pow`. See its documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx, specifically the table in the remarks section (parameter x < 0 and y not being an integer) Unfortunately, i can't make a suggestion, but i am hopeful that there is some mathematics library (or sample code) out there that does not have this limitation...

Comment: If you really need to raise a negative number to a fractional power, you can use [`Complex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.complex).

Comment: It's worth noting that you are working with doubles anyway.  As far as I know, Math.Sin, Math.Pow, etc. all take doubles as arguments and return doubles.  If you do an operation with a float and a double, the float gets converted to a double.  Do all your work in doubles (which will reduce your the amount of error in your calculations anyway) and convert the result to a float in the last step [[float ft = (float) (complicated expression in double)]].  Make sure that you wrap the entire expression in parens before casting to (float).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the definition of the Math.Pow function, see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx). Since your exponent is fixed and you're looking for the 3rd root as a real number, try something like

```
float t = -0.9165664;
float numerator = Math.Sin(t * Math.PI / 180.0f);
float denominator = 16.0f * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(t * Math.PI / 180.0f), 4)
float val = numerator / denominator;
float ft = Math.Sign(val) * (float)Math.Pow(Math.Abs(val), 1.0f / 3.0f));
```